# How do you force MySql to use an Index Range Scan instead of a Full Index Scan?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an index on `breadcrumbs`

```
CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `breadcrumbs` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_breadcrumbs` (`breadcrumbs`))
```

I'm running an update query:

```
update node
set breadcrumbs = concat(@newpath, substr(breadcrumbs, length(@oldpath)))
where breadcrumbs like @oldpath;
```

This query does a full index scan against `PRIMARY`.

Why would my select / update queries do a full index scan instead of an index range scan, and is there a way to *force* an index range scan?

**Edit:**

Apparently if using variables in MySql, it assumes that the search string, `@oldpath`, begins with a wildcard. Replacing `@oldpath` with its value, `'000%'` fixed the issue.

Is there any way to continue using variables but still have it work?